# pip install with index-url and extra-index-url does not work as expected

Tags: python, pip

I have a `pip.ini` file that includes a private repository on my local GitLab server. One of the packages on this repository is `shapely-2.0.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl` compiled with [Gohlke](https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/releases). When I run `pip install shapely --report 'report.txt'`, I see that it retrieves the package from the pypi repository (`https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages...`) instead of my private repo. However, when I remove the `extra-index-url = https://pypi.org/simple` line from `pip.ini`, I get the "correct" version of Shapely (the one compiled with Gohlke for the Cartopy package). Any suggestion why what I can change to get pip to first find a version of the package on my local server and if that does not exist use the version from pypi.org?

Here is the contents of my `pip.ini` file:

```
[global]
index-url = http://__token__:package@gitlab.local/api/v4/projects/293/packages/pypi/simple
extra-index-url = https://pypi.org/simple

[install]
trusted-host = gitlab.local
               pypi.org
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pip priority order with index-url and extra-index-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67253141/python-pip-priority-order-with-index-url-and-extra-index-url)