# Method to check that custom (non-PyPI) package is installed

Tags: python, python-import, pypi, python-packaging

We have some internal Python packages with the same names as packages on PyPI---say `package1`, `package2`, and `package3`. Occasionally some users install the PyPI versions by mistake, so I'm wondering if there's a standard way to verify they've installed the correct package.

My current idea is in our `package0`, which does not conflict with PyPI, but does import `package1`, `package2`, and `package3`, to do something like:

```py
# package0.__init__.py

import package1
import package2
import package2

for pkg in [package1, package2, package3]:
    try:
        assert "our-organization" in pkg.__url__
    except (AttributeError, AssertionError) as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            f"An incorrect version of {module.__name__} was detected. "
            "Please ensure you have installed correct internal version and not "
            f"a package on PyPI with the same name. ({exc})"
        )
```

Of course, this only works if they load `package0`, and not if they load `package1` directly in say a jupyter notebook or something.

Comment: I would recommend *not* shadowing a publicly available package like this, so that there is no ambiguity over which package should be installed. It's just as easy to say "use `foo-inhouse` instead of `foo`" as it is to say "install `foo` from here, not PyPi".

Comment: @chepner while that is probably good advice, it's a little late for us to change all our package names. And in general, there's no guarantee someone doesn't put `foo-inhouse` on PyPI in the future.

Comment: Where are the packages installed from? If you maintain your own package repository, then you have at least established that `foo-inhouse` needs to be installed from https://pypi.acme.com, rather than http://pypi.org. (Which may be the answer; I assume you are not doing that already, or it would be less likely that anyone accidentally installs the public version of your package instead of the private version.)

Comment: Our internal packages are installed from our org's gitlab. But we also install `numpy`, etc., from PyPI.

Comment: Are you using `pip` to install? If so, your users should be given `pip` configurations that look to your in-house repository to resolve packages before attempting to pull from the public repostory. If not, I still suggest that this is a problem to solve at the installation level, not with run-time checks to make sure the right doppelgänger is installed.

Comment: @chepner "*…`pip` configurations that look to your in-house repository to resolve packages before attempting to pull from the public repostory.*" AFAIK that's impossible. `pip` doesn't prioritize the index URL and extra URLs, it downloads packages from whatever URL it can, in no specific order.

Comment: Huh. I'd have expected there would be, but @phd is right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67253141/python-pip-priority-order-with-index-url-and-extra-index-url

Comment: You might be better off setting them to *only* use a local / internal repository, and setting *that* up to redirect / mirror the correct sources.

Comment: @CrazyChucky That might have been what I was thinking of.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using [*`importlib.metadata`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) to introspect the metadata of the installed packages. You could check for some specific value in the metadata, one of the URLs for example (as you suggest in your question), or a [trove classifier](https://pypi.org/classifiers/) maybe (the ones prefixed with `Private ::` might be good candidates since no such trove classifier can ever be on *PyPI*), or a combination of multiple metadata values.